# R: How to pass a name of DataFrame to a function, if a name is created by function

Tags: r, function-call

I have an example, where one dataframe is created in gWidgets's gdfedit function, but the name is not fixed (changes according to another vector). I want to pass this dataframe to another function, but I don't know how.

My code is a bit more complex, but this example sums up my problem:

```
 example <- function(df1, df2){
   df1$v3 <- df2$v1
 }

 x <- "01"
 df1 <- data.frame(v1=c(1,2,3), v2=c(6,7,8))
 gdfedit(items= df1, name=paste("df", x, sep = '' ), container = gwindow() , expand=TRUE)

 example(df1, paste("df", x, sep = '' )) #this obviously doesn't work.
```

I could go througt the vector of 'x' with for() and if() loop, but I want to have more elegant solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `get` while passing dataframe to your function.

```r
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
library(RGtk2Extras)

#your defined function
example <- function(x1, x2, x1_col, x2_col){
  x1[, x1_col] <- x2[, x2_col]
  return(x1)
}

#sample data
x <- "01"
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(6,7,8))

#edit dataframe and save it as a new dataframe
gdfedit(items = df1, name = paste0("df", x), container = gwindow(), expand = T)

#call function
example(df1, get(paste0("df", x)), "new_column", "v1")
```

which gives (if I save `df1` 'as is' in `df01`)

```
  v1 v2 new_column
1  1  6          1
2  2  7          2
3  3  8          3
```

(**Note:** I have slightly modified your function definition)